# PHP - Get element of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this portion of code : $output1 is an array()

```
$nn = count($output1);
for ($ii=0; $ii<$nn; $ii++)
{

  fwrite($fp,$ii."\r\n");
  fwrite($fp,$nn."\r\n");
  fwrite($fp, $output1[$ii]."\r\n");


  echo "</br>";
}
```

In this case the array contain one element but this is not standard.

```
 fwrite($fp,$ii."\r\n"); -> write in the file the value 0
 fwrite($fp,$nn."\r\n"); -> write in the file the value 1
 fwrite($fp, $output1[$ii]."\r\n"); -> Write Nothing!!!
```

Why?

Comment: `print_r($output1);` - what does it give?

Comment: 1 what? The key, the value? Arrays are denoted by `[key] => "Value"`

Comment: this is a background process and I don't print

Comment: @Qirel this line fwrite($fp, print_r($output1)."\r\n"); (insert value 1 in file)

Comment: Alright. Although, since `$output1` is an array, wouldn't using a `foreach`-loop be easier? They are designed to be used for arrays. Example: `foreach ($output1 as $key=>$value) { fwrite($fp,$key."\r\n");  fwrite($fp, count($output1)."\r\n");  fwrite($fp, $value."\r\n"); }`

Comment: @Qirel the three instuction insert in file : 0 , 1 , nothing

Comment: Which means that you have an array with 1 element, which has index/key 0, with value ` ` (empty). Did you adapt to the `foreach` I suggested, or did you stick with the `for`-loop?

Comment: @Qirel if I have one element in array why with this instrucion fwrite($fp, $output1[$ii]."\r\n"); I don't fetch?

Comment: If `$ii` matches the key, yes. But from what you described, the *value* is *empty*!